# How to access tableau server without login

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau and I want to integrate tableau server in our application through Iframe, I am passing HTTP URL with authentication details like username and password but whenever I am accessing tableau it is asking for username and password.So please suggest me that how i can access tableau without redirecting to login page.

Comment: One option is to grant access to the built in guest user. You lose any functionality around using the username() function and knowing who is using your workbook, but guess access does not require a login.

Comment: @SamM Guest users can only be used with Core-based licenses of Tableau Server though

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Tableau community](https://community.tableau.com/thread/116945) you can't do this through the URL:

> There is no built-in mechanism to pass a username/password on the URL
>   as doing so gives "bad people" a super-duper-easy way to hack into
>   Tableau Server itself. As a hacker, all I'd have to do is "sit on the
>   wire", watch requests go to Tableau, and I could harvest everyone's
>   usernames and passwords. Scary stuff!

But there is a solution for built in credentials if you have a security mechanism on your end:

> You might want to read up on Tableau Server's ability to do Trusted
>   Tickets authentication. You could essentially tell Tableau Server to
>   "Trust" whatever other security mechanism is authenticating your users
>   (I assume you have one).  If you don't have another mechaism to
>   authenticate users before they get to Tableau Server, there's not too
>   much you can do.

More on Trusted Authentication from [Tableau website](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm):

> Trusted authentication simply means that you have set up a trusted
>   relationship between Tableau Server and one or more web servers. When
>   Tableau Server receives requests from these trusted web servers it
>   assumes that your web server has handled whatever authentication is
>   necessary

Setting this up requires you to [add the trusted IP addresses](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_trustIP.htm) to your Tableau server. This is done by stopping `tabadmin` and then running the following command, followed by saving this config and restarting:

```
tabadmin set wgserver.trusted_hosts "<trusted IP addresses or host names>"
```

Once this is done you have to configure your web server so it can [request tickets from Tableau server](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_webrequ.htm) using a POST request to `http://<server name>/trusted`. These tickets must then be included into the script.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't sort of break the terms-of-use conditions (even though technically possible)? I'm assuming the use-case here would be to open Tableau Server report embedding for users without a license?

Comment: You always have to specify a user to get a 'ticket', but indeed you could possibly just use one single user in your configuration independent of who opens a webpage. I don't know whether Tableau server has systems in place that try to catch this. Possibly it will only accept one ticket for one user at the same time.